# Control GHC build options from environment variable using Cabal (Haskell)

Tags: haskell, compilation, environment-variables, ghc, cabal

Is it possible to build Haskell project using Cabal and control the GHC flags from environment variable?

in my project.cabal file there is a section 'GHC-Options', which controlls the flags, but I would love to additional set them from command line.

Comment: [Cabal flags](http://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/developing-packages.html#configurations) are not sufficient for your use case?

Comment: @JoachimBreitner - Thank you, Cabal flags seems to solve my problems, but I havent found anywhere how to set them from command line. I've tried several ways, but it did not worked for me.

Comment: `cabal configure -fflagname` or `cabal install -fflagname`, also [see here](http://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/installing-packages.html#controlling-flag-assignments).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only have on/off flags, you should use [Cabal flags](http://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/developing-packages.html#configurations).

Comment: The limitation of only on/off flags doesn't disturb me right now, but what can I do if I would to use in the future flags, which will allow me to pass an argument etc?

Answer (score 2):

Use `build-type: Configure` in the top level of your cabal file.

Write a `configure` script (i.e. a shell script at the top level of your package named "configure" - it doesn't have to be autotools style). It should read the environmental variable and produce a file called *package*.buildinfo, with "*package*" appropriately substituted.

The format of this file is theoretically described in the cabal user guide. The file should simply contain the build information fields as described in section 3.3.2.9 of the cabal user guide. Namely, the `build-depends`, `other-modules`, `hs-source-dirs`, `default-extensions`, `other-extensions`, `extensions`, `build-tool-depends`, `build-tools`, `buildable`, `ghc-options`, `ghc-prof-options`, `ghc-shared-options`, `includes`, `install-includes`, `include-dirs`, `c-sources`, `cxx-sources`, `asm-sources`, `cmm-sources`, `js-sources`, `extra-libraries`, `extra-ghci-libraries`, `extra-bundled-libraries`, `extra-lib-dirs`, `cc-options`, `cpp-options`, `cxx-options`, `ld-options`, `pkgconfig-depends`, `frameworks`, `extra-frameworks-dirs` and `mixins` fields that go in an an indent section. They need not be indented. These will be merged with the equivalent fields in the `library` section of your cabal file. (The User Guide describes the ability to include `executable` sections, but I can't make them work right now.)

So if you wanted a string in your code to reflect the content of `$PATH`, set up your cabal file and write a configure script like this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
echo 'cpp-options: -DCOMPILE_TIME_PATH="'$PATH'"' > my-package.buildinfo
```

And then you can write a .hs file

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE CPP #-}
module WhyNot where

compileTimePath :: String
compileTimePath = COMPILE_TIME_PATH
```

Cabal user guide: https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/developing-packages.html